# Load 2 select - PHP - Xajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select, xajax

I have 2 select, and I need to load at open the window. The second select It depends of the first, but dont load. The back-end it works, because with the method onchange both select load.
I'm using XAJAX, MYSQL AND PHP.

This is my javascript

```
window.onload = function () 
{
xajax_CargarTorneos();
CargarJornadas();//this method doesnt work
}

function CargarJornadas()
{
var id_torneo = $("#selTorneo").val();
xajax_CargarJornadas(id_torneo);
//
}

//this method it works
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#selTorneo").change(function(){
        CargarJornadas();
  });
});
```

Comment: Call your second xajax call, at the end of the first xajax call. $response->script("CargarJornadas();"); Of topic, by the way, have a look on jaxon-php, next generation of xajax.

Comment: Yeah, That I did and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look jaxon-php.